# Xcode can't renew team provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

When renewing in Organizer, I get this error message:

You are not allowed to perform this operation.  Please check with one of your Team Admins, or, if you need further assistance, please contact Apple Developer Program Support.
http://developer.apple.com/support

Comment: Hey, admins, calm down. This is normal question, you have too strict rules about what should be asked... I don't like stackoverflow because of this. Voted UP!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I agree. This is a question that is definitely relevant to coding, and one that I'd also like the answer to!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem for me was that my Apple identity still was a subuser for the developer account of one of my past clients (and it seems that didn't have the permissions to generate a team provisioning profile). After they deleted my subuser role on their account, I could renew the team provisioning profile without problems.